# I am trying to assert that below method is true But I am getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io, ts-jest

So basically I am able to get the text for all the buttons but I am getting the error which says Undefined when asserting that it's true. Please I need help, let me know if more information is needed. Thank you

```
async isNoticationsEnabled(type: string) {

    const notificationType = await this.getNotificationsTypeByText(type);
    const selectContainer = await notificationType.$$('.NotificationTypeSchedule__selectContainer');
    const sms = selectContainer[1];
    const mobilePush = selectContainer[2];
    const webPush = selectContainer[3];
    const enabled = [];
    enabled.push(sms, mobilePush, webPush)
    for (let i = 0; i < enabled.length; i++) {
      const elements = enabled[i];
      if(await elements?.getText() === 'On') {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: undefined

      42 |     expect(await NotificationsTabs.isNotificationSectionDisplayed()).toBe(true)
      43 |     await NotificationsTabs.scrollTo('Note Mentions')
    > 44 |     expect(await NotificationsTabs.isNoticationsEnabled('Note Mentions')).toBe(true);
         |                                                                            ^
      45 |   });
      46 | });
```

Comment: That means your loop over `enabled` doesn't find what it expects to find when you call this method with the `"Note Mentions"` argument. This is based on what gets returned from the first two lines of your function, which you have not posted the code for, so we can't tell you why this is happening. But try a `console.log(selectContainer)` in your function and see what the output is in each case.

Comment: selectorContainer is actually getting the right elements. When I apply getText() on those selected elements it is actually getting the right text which is "On" for all three   elements. Those are the only elements which are enabled on the page

Comment: I Fixed the issue by selecting the right xpath to get all the text. Thank you